# displaying image using a label

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qimage, qlabel

I have converted a numpy array into a pixmap to display it on a label within my GUI. When I run the program, the GUI closes for some reason (no error messages).

```
height, width = input_image.shape
bytesPerLine = 3 * width
qImg = QtGui.QImage(input_image.data, width, height, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
pixmap01 = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImg)
self.pixmap_image = QtGui.QPixmap(pixmap01)
self.ui.label_imageDisplay.setPixmap(self.pixmap_image)
self.ui.label_imageDisplay.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
self.ui.label_imageDisplay.setScaledContents(True)
self.ui.label_imageDisplay.setMinimumSize(1,1)
self.ui.label_imageDisplay.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

from scipy.ndimage import imread
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

input_image = imread({your filename})
height, width, channels = input_image.shape
bytesPerLine = channels * width
qImg = QtGui.QImage(input_image.data, width, height, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
pixmap01 = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImg)
pixmap_image = QtGui.QPixmap(pixmap01)
label_imageDisplay = QtWidgets.QLabel()
label_imageDisplay.setPixmap(pixmap_image)
label_imageDisplay.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
label_imageDisplay.setScaledContents(True)
label_imageDisplay.setMinimumSize(1,1)
label_imageDisplay.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]